# How to prove that $\arg: S^1\setminus\{-1\}\to (-\pi,\pi)$ is continuous? (With restrictions.)

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, continuity

> How to prove that $\arg: S^1\setminus\{-1\}\to (-\pi,\pi)$ is continuous?

**Restrictions: for this proof we cant use logarithms, derivatives or integrals.**

I know that $\arg^{-1}$ is bijective and continuous, hence $\arg$ is bijective, but I dont have a clue about how to prove it continuity.

The argument function is defined as the map $e^{i\alpha}\mapsto \alpha$. I thought about define the map $e^{i\alpha}\mapsto e^\alpha$, but it continuity is not more clear than the previous map (the idea behind is that for $e^\alpha$ I can use it strict monotonicity to prove that $e^\alpha\mapsto\alpha$ is continuous).

Other idea is try to show that $\arg^{-1}(\Bbb B(x,\delta))=\Bbb B(e^{ix},\epsilon)$, i.e. $\arg^{-1}$ is open, but I dont have a clue about how to prove this formally. Some help will be appreciated, thank you.

---

**UPDATE:**

Attempted proof. We choose some closed interval of the kind $C_n:=[-\pi+\frac1n,\pi-\frac1n]$. Then the restriction of $\arg^{-1}$ to $C_n$ and it image is homeomorphic i.e. $\arg$ is continuous in $\arg^{-1}(C_n)$, because every closed set in $C_n$ is compact and hence it image is compact, what is a definition of continuity for $\arg$.

Because this is true for all $n\in\Bbb N$ then it is true for the entire domain $(-\pi,\pi)$.$\Box$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Suggestion**: The inverse map $f:(-\pi, \pi) \to S^{1} \setminus\{-1\}$ defined by $f(t) = \exp(it)$ is a continuous bijection, so is a homeomorphism when restricted to an arbitrary closed interval $[a, b] \subset (-\pi, \pi)$, and every point of $S^{1} \setminus\{-1\}$ lies in the interior of the image of some compact set.

Comment: If I understood correctly: we can reason that because every closed set in $(-\pi,\pi)$ is compact then $\arg^{-1}$ is an open and closed function too, and then $\arg$ is continuous, right?

Comment: Almost: The key point is, every point of $(-\pi, \pi)$ is in the _interior_ of _some_ compact set, and every compact set maps homeomorphically under $f$ (hence under $\arg = f^{-1}$).

Comment: Ah, right... not every closed set in $(-\pi,\pi)$ is compact, by example the sets $(-\pi,a]$ for $a\in(-\pi,\pi)$ are closed but not compact.

Comment: Actually, I've omitted the important detail that $f$ is _proper_ (the inverse image of every compact set is compact); without this condition, there are continuous bijections of the type $t \mapsto (\sin t, \sin(2t))$ for $-\pi < t < \pi$ whose inverse is not continuous at $(0, 0)$. The suggestion is still how I'd approach the proof, however.

Comment: From the locally compact condition of $(-\pi,\pi)$ we can conclude that $\arg$ is continuous (local homeomorphism) at every point and so it is continuous. This is a proof, right? Just to confirm.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not quite enough: You were correct about showing $f$ is an open mapping. That is, my first comment was a bit sloppy; it's important also to show $f$ is open, or that _every_ compact subset of $S^{1} \setminus\{-1\}$ is the image of a compact subset of $(-\pi, \pi)$. (In this particular case that's not difficult, but the detail does require attention.)

Comment: I dont follow totally your comments, can you check if the proof in the updated answer is correct? To see different answers I will quit for some time the validity of this answer, I hope you understand.

Comment: 1. De-selecting my answer is perfectly understandable under the circumstances. :) 2. The general problem is, while the image of a compact subset $C$ under $f$ is homeomorphic to $C$, the image of the interior of $C$ might, _a priori_, not be open _in the target space_. (The image of the interior of $C$ _is_ open in the image $f(C)$, because $f$ maps $C$ homeomorphically to $f(C)$.) This phenomenon doesn't occur for $f = \arg^{-1}$, but this fact needs to be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Using an $\epsilon - \delta$ argument:

Let $\alpha_0\in (-\pi,\pi)$ and $0 < \epsilon < 1$. Choose $\delta = 2 \sin(\frac{\epsilon}{2})$. Then $0 < \delta < 1$. For all $\alpha \in (-\pi,\pi)$, $\lvert e^{i\alpha} - e^{i\alpha_0}\rvert < \delta$ implies $2\sin(\frac{\lvert \alpha - \alpha_0\rvert}{2}) < \delta$. Indeed, $$\lvert e^{i\alpha} - e^{i\alpha_0}\rvert = \lvert e^{i(\alpha+\alpha_0)/2}[e^{i(\alpha - \alpha_0)/2} - e^{-i(\alpha-\alpha_0)/2}]\rvert = \lvert e^{i(\alpha-\alpha_0)/2} - e^{-i(\alpha-\alpha_0)/2}\rvert = 2\left\lvert \sin\frac{\lvert \alpha-\alpha_0\rvert}{2}\right\rvert$$ and since $\lvert \alpha - \alpha_0\rvert < 2\pi$, then $$2\left\lvert \sin \frac{\lvert \alpha - \alpha_0\rvert}{2}\right\rvert = 2\sin \frac{\lvert \alpha - \alpha_0\rvert}{2}$$ Since $0 \le \sin(\frac{\lvert \alpha - \alpha_0\rvert}{2}) < \frac{\delta}{2} < 1$, then $\frac{\lvert \alpha - \alpha_0\rvert}{2} < \sin^{-1}(\frac{\delta}{2})$. Hence, $\lvert \alpha - \alpha_0\rvert < 2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\delta}{2}\right) = \epsilon$. Since $\alpha_0$ was arbitrary, the $\arg$ is continuous.

Comment: Ah, beautiful. I just dont tried a direct $\epsilon{-}\delta$ approach.